# Bind Combobox to Array in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have two fields.
Workshop | Participation Status

Workshop is a list of workshops that have been conducted. Whereas Participation Status Shows the Participant Status i.e Participated, Not-Participated, Guest Etc. For each Workshop there is a select box showing the possible participation status. The List of Workshop is dynamic.

So A typical row would be like

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="workshop_attended">Workshop 1
<select v-model="participation_status">
<option value="P">Participant</option>
<option value="G">Guest</option>


<input type="checkbox" v-model="workshop_attended">Workshop 2
<select v-model="participation_status">
<option value="P">Participant</option>
<option value="G">Guest</option>
```

And So on.

In my Script I am using CDN btw.

```
<script>
var vm=new Vue({
 el:'#app'
})
```

So if someone selects a workshop then they select their Participation Status. I want to store the Workshop and the status in a structure given below.

```
this.workshops.push({workshop:"Workshop 1", status:"P" }
```

However i am having problems going about it. Since all Select Boxes are bound to the same model, a change in one triggers a change in all. I want to add the info to workshops object as soon as a particular workshop is selected and participation status selected. I am having trouble going about it.

I am new to Vue and am using CDN without the Single Page Application stuff.

Thanks in Advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/zeenux/peL9acfh/7/#&togetherjs=0Qeqn23QRj

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have a dynamic list of workshop.

Iterate on it then :

```
<div v-for="(workshop, index) in workshops" :key="index" >    
<input type="checkbox" v-model="workshop.selected">
{{workshop.name}}
<select v-model="workshop.status">
<option value="P">Participant</option>
<option value="G">Guest</option>
</div>
```

Instead of using v-model for the checkbox, maybe you should bind a function to @input that push when true, and splice when false